# How to change disk name from /dev/sda1 to /dev/sd127 in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk

How do I change the name of the disk in ubuntu 14.04 LTS server from /dev/sda1 to something else like /dev/sd127?

This is a regular EXT4 striped disk attached to the system.

Comment: I believe exactly this question, albeit in different words, has been answered over on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422500/how-do-you-swap-dev-sda-with-dev-sdb.

Comment: Do you really need to rename it, or is an alternate name acceptable (i.e. both `sda1` and `sd127` point to the same device versus `sda1` no longer existing as a device name once `sd127` has been defined)?

Comment: You can mount or access based on the uuid and that would ensure consistency

Comment: I don't think that's possible because sda represents SCSI type of storage device,  and that's handled by specific driver. So you'd potentially have to change the driver. But that's a guess. What exactly the purpose you're trying to achieve ? Perhaps we can suggest something better. Please provide more context